# ngOnInit does not run on error page component

Tags: angular, error-handling, ngoninit

Angular 4 application.

I am trying to make an error page in order to show some information about the unhandled exception that may occur. The `GlobalErrorHandler` intercepts eventual errors and redirects the user to a page consisting of a single `ErrorComponent`. When the error occurs the page is shown, but life cycle hooks do not get called.

**ErrorHandler** :

```js
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(
        private injector: Injector
    ) {
        // The true paramter tells Angular to rethrow exceptions, so operations like 'bootstrap' will result in an error
        // when an error happens. If we do not rethrow, bootstrap will always succeed.
        super(true);
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);

        if (!router.url.startsWith('/error')) {
            router.navigate(['/error']);
        }

        super.handleError(error); 
    }

}
```

**ErrorComponent** :

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'error-desc',
    template: '<h1>Error page = {{code}}</h1>'
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    public code: string = '';

    constructor(
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // not called
        this.code="AAAA";
        console.log("OnInit");
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log("OnDestroy");
    }
}
```

Working demo on [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/koh5iPUcaN196mslPVwY/).

How I can fix this? Maybe someone knows workaround?
Thanks

Comment: put Your code please

Comment: The code is in planker. See the link in description

Comment: @Albert I experience the same problem after upgrading from 4.1 to 4.4. BTW You should include the code inside your question, not an external website, see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) : "*If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*"

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15946) about that concern.

Comment: @n00dl3, you are right, it is my oversight about code in question. I will be more attentive in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

After finding [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15946#issuecomment-330873024). It seems you just have to run your `router.navigate(...)` code inside angular's zone to get the redirection up and running :

**ErrorHandler :**

```js
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector private zone: NgZone) {
        super();
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);
        super.handleError(error);
        if (!router.url.startsWith('/error')) {
            this.zone.run(()=>router.navigate(['/error']));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting, `handleError` method run outside `zone`

Comment: I had same issue receiving a payment from `PayPal Checkout` and redirecting the user to a success page... anyway, running the `router` inside angular's `NgZone` fixed my issue... Thanks!